# What's the difference between 我去吃飯 (去 + Action) and 我要吃飯了 (要+Action+了)?

Tags: difference

What is the difference among the following two sentences?

- 我 去 吃飯
- 我 要 吃飯 了

According to my current knowledge, both translate to *''I am going to eat''*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- 我吃飯 =  I eat dinner (meal)
- 我(去)吃飯 = I (go) eat dinner
- 我(要)吃飯 = I (have to/ want to) eat dinner
- 我(要)(去)吃飯  = I (have to/ want to) (go) eat dinner

You can add final particle '了' (indicate change of situation) to all the above examples :

- 我吃飯了 =  I eat dinner (meal) now- *了 indicates situation change from not eating to eating*
- 我(去)吃飯了 = I (go) eat dinner now- *了 indicates situation change from not going to going*
- 我(要)吃飯了 = I (have to/ want to) eat dinner now - *了 indicates situation change from not have eat to have to eat*
- 我(要)(去)吃飯了  = I (have to/ want to)(go) eat my dinner now - *了 indicates situation change from not have to go to have to go*

> 去 + Action vs 要+Action+了

More examples:

- 我看電影 = I watch movies
- 我(要)看電影 = I (have to/ want to) watch movies
- 我(去)看電影 = I (go) watch movies
- 我(要)(去)看電影了 = I (have to/ want to) (go) watch movies now- 了 indicates situation change from not going to going

Answer (score 5):

我 去 吃飯 sounds that you will go somewhere(eg. A restaurant) to have an eat. The sentence is used in response to  你干什么去？，干嘛去？

我 要 吃飯 了 sounds like, you have your meal handy/ready and you are just about to eat it. Or it's time for me to eat. Or just simply I am going to eat. Basically, the sentence is used when you want to tell somebody you are going to have a meal.

Answer (score 3):

我 去 吃飯 I'm going to get something to eat.
我 要 吃飯 了 I wanna get my teeth into something.

我 去食堂 吃飯 I'm going to the canteen to get something to eat.
我要吃午饭。I want some lunch.

Comment: 我 去食堂 吃飯 = I go to the canteen to have a meal.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, both can be translated as 'I am going to eat'. Yet "going" has completely different meanings in the two sentences.

The first one is "actually going / moving yourself to a place where you have food" and the second is "planning to, intending to have food".

This question is about ambiguity of English, not Chinese ;)

PS A better translation of the first phrase using "going" would be "I am going to have food / to a restaurant etc"

Answer (score 2):

- 我去吃饭 literally means "I go to have my meal" because 去 can be    translated as "go" in Chinese.  我要吃饭了 literally means "I am going to
  have my meal". And in some context, it can also mean "I must have my
  meal".
- The first one sounds more like you have already known or      planned
  what you are going to eat and now all you have to do is to   eat it
  directly.
- Q：You seem to be in a hurry. (你似乎急急忙忙的) What are you    going to do?
  (你要去做什么？)
- A：I go to have my dinner. (我去吃晚饭) I'm gonna be    late.    (我要迟到了)
- The second one is more frequently used in the context that it's time to have a meal and you decide to eat it.
- E.g. Sorry to interrupt you. But I have to take a leave. I'm going to have a meal.
  (抱歉打断你了，但是我得离开一会。我要吃饭了。)